# SharedPreference giving "Unable to establish connection on channel." when used inside flutter_background_service

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-sharedpreference

I'm using [flutter_background_service](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background_service) to start a service to fetch data from Cloud.
It's working just fine in Android. But when I run on an iOS Simulator, I get the Above mentioned error.

```
void syncData() async {

  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  Fimber.plantTree(DebugTree());
  Fimber.d("SyncData() called");
  final service = FlutterBackgroundService();
  Fimber.d("Sync Service Started: $service");
  ApiRepo apiRepo = ApiRepo();

  bool isPatientUploaded = false;
  Fimber.d("isPatientUploaded: $isPatientUploaded");

  if(Platform.isAndroid) {
    SharedPreferencesAndroid.registerWith();
    PathProviderAndroid.registerWith();
    FlutterBackgroundServiceAndroid.registerWith();
  } else if (Platform.isIOS) {
    SharedPreferencesIOS.registerWith();
    PathProviderIOS.registerWith();
    FlutterBackgroundServiceIOS.registerWith();
  }
  Fimber.d("Fetching Shared Preference");
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  Fimber.d("Fetched Shared Preference: $prefs");
  String? authToken = prefs.getString(PrefKeys.TOKEN);

    ...........
}
```

I can see the Log till "Fetching Shared Preference" and then get an error afterwards. I don't see the Next log.

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null)
```

This is how I'm starting the Service

```
startSync() async {
    Fimber.d("startSync() called");
    final service = FlutterBackgroundService();
    Fimber.i("Configuring $service");
    bool? isConfigured = await service.configure(
        iosConfiguration: IosConfiguration(
            onForeground: syncData, onBackground: syncData, autoStart: false),
        androidConfiguration: AndroidConfiguration(
          onStart: syncData,
          isForegroundMode: true,
          autoStart: false,
          foregroundServiceNotificationContent: "Uploading Data to Cloud...",
          foregroundServiceNotificationTitle: "Selfi",
        ));
    await DatabaseHelper().db;
    Fimber.i("isConfigured: $isConfigured");
    if (isConfigured) {
      Fimber.d("Starting Service");
      bool isStarted = await service.startService();
      Fimber.d("Service Started: $isStarted");
    }
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried simply killing you app and restarting? Looks like you may just init `SharedPreferences` and app just can't see it

Comment: Any solution for this ?

Comment: @Vishak A Kamath have you solve it ?

Comment: same problem here, did you solve it?

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue with Shared Preference, rebuilding the app solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can stop and restart the app.. Sometimes the IDE doesn't pick the package installed instantly.
hope it helps :)